# where magento stores country full name

Tags: php, magento, country, country-codes

I have spent hours searching to find where magento stores full county name.
We can get a full list of countries using this code:

```
$_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
    ->loadData()
    ->toOptionArray(false);
```

This will return an array with country code and name, I investigated the directory module, and found out this call gets data from the table

> directory_county

But this table don't have full county name! So where is it stored?
and how is it retrieved using that call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you need table name. What is the purpose ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so to compensate for my wrong answer. Here is how this works:

1. /lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml  - if your store is in english, else another xml in the same directoery is read. Every country is there and its code under the xml tag `<territory>`
2. The xml is cached  using the Zend_Cache_Core class.
3. /lib/Zend/Locale.php - function getTranslation invokes the lib/Zend/Cache/Core.php class
   to load from the cache.

Example: If you change the name of some country in en.xml  and clear the magento cache. You will see the change when u invoke your code again.

Comment: I'm using en.xml too, also made a change and it didn't appear,
did you try it?
to see if I'm modifying wrong file

Comment: Aren't those the language names?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Zend_Local translation.

```
<?php
$code = 'EN';
echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->getTranslation($code, 'Territory', null, 2);
?>
```

Use the column 'iso2_code' from the table 'directory_country' for your $code.

Answer (score 1):

Full country names are not stored in database. Magento uses inbuilt Zend functionality.

Check file: `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/Translation.php` for full list.

Comment: yes this file contains full list .. but I modified one country name and printed out all countries .. the change didn't appear :(
I don't understand why !!!!!
(I make sure there is no caching in browser)

Answer (score 0):

Magneto only stores country codes in DB, and relies for names on Zend's Locale module to provide translated names, for different locale.

By the `toOptionArray` method it invokes the `Zend_Locale` class to get the translated value.

Refer `$name = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($data['value']);`, which gets to `Mage_Core_Model_Locale` and then to `Zend_Locale`.

It decides which of the node from the data to read, by the switch case statement in `Zend_Locale_Data::getContent()` line# 962, 963

Magento caches the names, so if you make any change to `XML` files, make sure to clean your cache folder to get what you seek.