# Change Magento Shipping country name. "Hong Kong SAR China" to "Hong Kong"

Tags: magento

I need to change the default displayed Country name of "Hong Kong SAR China" to "Hong Kong" in the shipping address country option. This will need to be throughout, and for shipping labels.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try this answer on [how to change a country code's name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932715/where-magento-stores-country-full-name) (and note the instruction to clear the cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your country name and replace the new name in below file

`/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml` - if your store is in English, else another xml in the same directory is read. Every country is there and its code under the xml tag `<territory>`

**Note:**  clear the Magento cache. You will see the change.